# mocha testing promises reports failure but need to control-c to get back control

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js

I am trying to use mocha for the first time.  My dependency

```
"devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^4.0.1"
  }
```

The test is trivial

```
describe("test 2", function () {
    it("test promise that failes", function () {
        return Promise.reject("I failed")
    })
})
```

When I

```
npm test
```

The test fails as expected but I need to ctnl c to get the prompt

```
Terminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

Typing Y give me back the command prompt.

I thought mocha handled rejected promises.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the test script portion of the package.json

it contained

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --recursive --watch"
  },
```

removing the --recursive --watch solved the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misunderstood your question